# Не могу отпарсить JSON

Tags: javascript, java, json, spring-boot, xhr

Нужно получить данные вот из такого **JSON`a:**

```
{
"timeStamp":"2022-04-05T13:51:06.6688191",
"statusCode":200,
"status":"OK",
"message":"Races retrieved",
"data":  
       [
        {"id":"1","carOwner":"Sergiy","time":"35s","date":"04/04/22","carToken":"dwafdawfaegfadfrfsvsf"},
        {"id":"2","carOwner":"Roman","time":"37s","date":"04/04/22","carToken":"dwafdawfaegffasadfrfsvsf"},
        {"id":"3","carOwner":"Yura","time":"36s","date":"04/04/22","carToken":"dwafdawfsacaegffasadfrfsvsf"},
        {"id":"4","carOwner":"Nazar","time":"55s","date":"04/04/22","carToken":"dwafdawfsacaegffas"},
        {"id":"5","carOwner":"Arsen","time":"34s","date":"04/04/22","carToken":"dwwfsacaegffas"}
       ]
}
```

Код **JS:**

> JavaScript не учил от слова совсем, писал бэкенд, не ругайтесь

```js
xhr.onload = function() {
    var object = xhr.response;
    for (var i=0;object.data.length;i++) {
        var owner = object.data[i].carOwner;
    }
    alert(owner);
    };
```

При попытке получаю вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот **REST Controller** на бэкенде:

```
@GetMapping("/list")
public ResponseEntity<Response> getRaces() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(
            Response.builder()
                    .timeStamp(now())
                    .data(raceService.findAll()) //return List<Race>
                    .message("Races retrieved")
                    .status(OK)
                    .statusCode(OK.value())
                    .build()
    );
}
```

[image]

---

```
console.log(object.data[0]['carOwner'])
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что у вас в объекте object? сделайте console.log

Comment: @vanesicks https://prnt.sc/avrti2Rx8KNE

Answer (score 0):

А можно целиком код с запросом а не с момента **xhr.load**...
Возможно забыли перевести "ответ" в **JSON** так как с сервера приходит в виде строки, а не массив данных. Перевести можно таким образом **xhr.responseType = 'json';** или таким **JSON.parse(xhr.response)**

Не понятно какого результата ты ждешь... переписывая переменную в теле цикла.
Исправил твой цикл с переменной возможно угадал

```js
var object = xhr.response;
    var owner = '' //если нужна строка
    var arrOwner = []//если нужен массив
    for (var i=0; i<object.data.length; i++) {
         owner += object.data[i].carOwner + ' ';
         arrOwner.push(object.data[i].carOwner)
    }
    alert(owner);
    alert(arrOwner);
```

Comment: function send() {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("user:user"));
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.send();
}

Comment: Тип и аутентификация у меня указаны

Comment: Надо все тело запроса, видеть.....  Да и в цикле у тебя ошибка (var i=0;object.data.length;i++) где условие напиши правильно  **i<object.data.length**  вот так должно быть   (var i=0; i<object.data.length; i++)

Comment: я уже всё решил, посмотри ответ выше